# How to create this sql statment to search in each record at the many table side?

Tags: sql, select

Now I have to create a query for search page depends on database that have 30 tables:

I will describe my requirement with an example:

there is a relation between table A and table B -> one to many  relation

If we consider that table A is for Students info and table B to save the courses for that student each year . it is only allowed to take 3 subjects each year so the structure will be as the following:

**Table A:** *ID ,Student-Name ,Tel#,Birthdate ......*

**Table B:** :*ID,StudentID,Date,Subject-one,Subject-two,Subject-three*

so the student can take any 3 subjects per year
I want to make a query for subject called X to get all students who take it at any year but only once

example for valid student:

```
  StudentID  Sub1  Sub2  Sub3  Year  
  60         Z     (X)    Y      1
  60         L      W     V      2
  60         M      P     Y      3
```

example for invalid student:

```
  StudentID  Sub1  Sub2  Sub3  Year  
  10         Z     (X)    O      1
  10         L      W     V      2
  10         O      P    (x)     3
```

i hope that to be clear enough for my problem

Comment: Does this logic necessarily have to be in the query or can it be handled through a script

Comment: What Kind OF SQL? Also, your problem would be much easier to solve with normalised tables. As a bonus, you could then allow people to take 4 subjects per year without rewriting your entire system.

Comment: @Asad :yeah well it was an example to make things easy but the real one is medicine so the patient could take specific one among all years so the doctor want to check who is this that patient who took only one type i think what i said is maybe complicated but if i found solution in the example above i would solve the real one :)

Comment: I will write a subquery and post it in a bit.

Comment: @podiluska it is not related to the normalization or the structure it is related to the data saved depend on the user who enter these data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with comments that you would be better with one row per subject in table 2 *(a normalised structure is virtually always better and more SQL friendly)*.

That said, you *can* solve it in your structure.

```
SELECT
  studentID
FROM
  table2
WHERE
     sub1 = 'x'
  OR sub2 = 'x'
  OR sub3 = 'x'
GROUP BY
  studentID
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 1
```

*(This assumes the student can't take the same subject twice in the same year.)*

Some varieties of SQL may allow the WHERE clause to be shortened...

```
WHERE
  'x' IN (sub1, sub2, sub3)
```

You can then pick up all the student details by putting this in a sub-query...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table1
INNER JOIN
(
  <put the above query here>
)
  AS lookup
    ON lookup.studentID = table1.studentID
```

**EDIT**

I don't understand your comment.  But an alternative (and potentially more generalisable) HAVING clause could be..

```
HAVING
  SUM(CASE WHEN sub1 = 'x' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN sub2 = 'x' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN sub3 = 'x' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  = 1
```

Comment: I think what is needed is for the student to have taken it only once over all years, no? That is why the second example is invalid. Edit: missed the disclaimer, sorry

Comment: @Asad - That's what this does.  If the student took the course in more than one year then `COUNT(*)` would be greater than 1.  *[In example2, the `COUNT(*)` is 2, and so the HAVING clauses excludes it from the results.]*

Comment: look what i need is to check all courses for each student for some condition how to form this query

Comment: @speciallife - This query returns the results that you asked for (it *will* return student id 60, but *won't* return student id 10).  Do you have a specific case where this construction is not helpful to you?

Comment: @Dems i will try it now and i will give you a feedback :)

Comment: Hey Dems, I'm not sure, but doesn't count apply to the base set and not the result set? I mean won't you just get first years?

Comment: @Asad - It will *not* count any records excluded by the `WHERE` clause.  It then counts all remaining input records that are aggregated into one record in the output result set.

Comment: mmmm i thought that there is a direct way with sql but this one will not work with me :( anyway i appreciate your help :)

Comment: @speciallife - This directly answers the example you gave, in two different ways.  If you can give example data that this does not work for, I am happy to show how this structure can be adopted to fit.  Perhaps create a sample data-set in SQL Fiddle, so as to test suggested answers?  *[For example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c52ec/3 ]*

Comment: This actually does answer the question beautifully, especially the last HAVING clause, which removes the need for the WHERE clause entirely. Perhaps you need help adapting the query to your specific case?

Comment: @Dems thanks really for your answer but can i ask you another question please if you dont mind :)? now as i mentioned i have many tables to fetch data from so some queries  need to make many innerjoin between tables and this make me confused is it good to use "And" to join tabled instead of innerjoin ?

Comment: @speciallife - `SELECT * FROM a, b, c WHERE a.id = b.id AND b.id = c.id` is an old style syntax.  It means the same as `SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id INNER JOIN c ON b.id = c.id`.  The `INNER JOIN` syntax is ANSI-92 standard, 20 years old now.  Many people still hold to the old style, but most see it as an ANTI-PATTERN. Some vendors even go as far as recommending it not be used. Particularly when using `OUTER JOIN`, where the old style become cumbersome.  But if you search SO about this topic, you will get many different points of view.

Comment: mmm but you know the problem with using innerjoin is if no matched record for one row in the other table it will return nothing

Comment: @speciallife - Then use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @Dems ok i will try to use it and sorry for asking a lot i appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this..
For a given subject X, you can run through a loop for every student to check if he is a valid student for that subject like this. Inside the loop:

```
IF(
(SELECT count(1) from TableB where Sub1 = 'X' and StudentID = 60 ) + 
(SELECT count(1) from TableB where Sub2 = 'X' and StudentID = 60 ) + 
(SELECT count(1) from TableB where Sub3 = 'X'and StudentID = 60 ) ) = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #ValidStudent(...)
END
```

You will have to put StudentID variable in place of 60 and at the end..

```
SELECT * FROM #ValidStudent
```

Comment: Suggesting a loop that can instead be refactored into  single SQL (set based) statement is a significant mis-use (anti-pattern) of an RDBMS.  This is effectively an unrolling (de-optimisation) of the `HAVING SUM(CASE)` answer I posted earlier.

Comment: thanks for answer but this will not work this way because with this i need to create a loop to go over all students ,so instead of that i can work on it with code behind because no direct way with sql to get the valid result

Comment: @Dems I agree with your comment.